# Nil when transferring data from TabbarController to ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, data-transfer

[image]I can’t understand what the mistake is,
an ordinary user should register, provided that everything is successful, the current user will show on `TabBarController`, and if you want him to convert to `print("\(currentUser)")`, then everything is fine. this user's protocol

Here I output to the console, everything is fine

```
import UIKit

class MainTabBarViewController: UITabBarController {
    
    var currentUser: MUser = MUser(username: "fdff",
                                   usersurname: "dfdf",
                                   phone: "dffd",
                                   sex: "dfb",
                                   avatarStringURL: "fgf",
                                   id: "gf",
                                   bithDate: "fggf")
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let messageVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "MessageVC") as! MessageVC
        messageVC.currentUser = currentUser
        print("\(currentUser)")
    }

}
```

but you see, I pass it on and in this controller the nil issues

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseFirestore

class MessageVC: UITableViewController {
    
    var chat = [MChat]()
    var currentUser: MUser!
   
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        print(chat[indexPath.row])
        print("\(currentUser)") // return nil
        
        let chatsVC = ChatsViewController(user: currentUser, chat: chat[indexPath.row])
        navigationController?.pushViewController(chatsVC, animated: true)
    }
    
}
```

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is `MessageVC` one of the tabs of `MainTabBarViewController`?

Comment: Try to instantiate the `MessageVC` from the storyboard and then pass current user.

Comment: Instance of MessageVC() named messVC will be deallocated after out of escaping viewDidLoad() scope.

Comment: Yes, MessageVC is a tab of MainTabBarViewController

Comment: *Yes, MessageVC is a tab of MainTabBarViewController* – So why for heaven's sake don't you get the reference to the `MessageVC` instance directly from the tab bar controller? `MessageVC()` creates a brand new instance of the controller which has nothing to do with the instance in the storyboard.

Comment: I added changes

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

Try to instantiate the `MessageVC` from the storyboard and then pass the data to it from the `TabBarController`.

Hold the reference of `MessageVC` globally outside `ViewDidLoad` and use it for navigation.

**Example**

```
class MainTabBarViewController: UITabBarController {
    
    var currentUser: MUser = MUser(username: "fdff",
                                   usersurname: "dfdf",
                                   phone: "dffd",
                                   sex: "dfb",
                                   avatarStringURL: "fgf",
                                   id: "gf",
                                   bithDate: "fggf")
    // Declare Message VC instance
    var messageVC : MessageVC!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       // Instantiate from Storyboard
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        messageVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "VCIdentifier")
        messageVC.currentUser = currentUser
        print("\(currentUser)")
    }

}
```

**Update:** Access Child ViewController from TabBarController

```
func accessMessageVC() {
    // Use your viewcontroller index.
    let vc = self.viewControllers![2] as! MessageVC
    messageVC.currentUser = currentUser
}
```

Call this method from TabBarController's `ViewDidLoad`

Comment: ``` let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let messageVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "MessageVC") as! MessageVC

        messageVC.currentUser = currentUser ```

and in storybord added storyboardID

not working did not help

Comment: @Eugene I don't get it, what do you want to say?

Comment: I say that didn’t help, it also returns nil

Comment: @Eugene How do you set the MessageVC to the TabBarController? Can you please add that code, I have a feeling you are doing something wrong there.

Comment: @Eugene Use globally declared `MessageVC` instance to set as a one of ViewController of TabBarController. Don't create another instance of `MessageVC`.

Comment: I added changes

Comment: @Eugene I have updated my answer, access MessageVC directly from TabbarController.

Comment: @Eugene  have you checked it?